# Regex - Multiple Negative Lookbehinds

Tags: regex, r, pcre, lookbehind

I'm working on matching strings from a write-in survey field which asks about a major field of study.

For the "Arts" section I want to match all types of Arts degrees, but specifically exclude liberal arts, culinary arts and language arts.

This code correctly excludes "liberal arts", but I have been unable to list multiple things to exclude.

I am using the grepl function in R with perl-compatible regexps.

```
field_1_1_arts <-c("\\b(dance|ballet|design|film|(?<!liberal )arts?|music|photograph(ic|y)|theat(er|re)|performing|visual)\\b") 

data$field_1_1_arts <- grepl(field_1_1_arts,data$major_fields,ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

I have tried:

```
#this allows both liberal and culinary to pass
field_1_1_arts <-c("\\b(dance|ballet|design|film|(?<!liberal )arts?|(?<!culinary )arts?|music|photograph(ic|y)|theat(er|re)|performing|visual)\\b") 

#this gives an invalid expression error
field_1_1_arts <-c("\\b(dance|ballet|design|film|(?<!(liberal|culinary) )arts?|music|photograph(ic|y)|theat(er|re)|performing|visual)\\b")
```

Comment: what about `l[ia]` :} only matches language, culinary, and liberal but none of the others, eg, `x <- c('dance','ballet','design','film','liberal','arts','music','photograph', 'theater','performing','visual','culinary', 'language'); grep('l[ia]', x, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude more than `libral`, just add more negative lookbehinds, e.g.:

```
"\\b(dance|ballet|design|film|(?<!liberal )(?<!culinary )(?<!language )arts?|music|photograph(ic|y)|theat(er|re)|performing|visual)\\b"
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS3vR9/1)

You can also use `|`:

```
"\\b(dance|ballet|design|film|(?<!liberal |culinary |language )arts?|music|photograph(ic|y)|theat(er|re)|performing|visual)\\b"
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS3vR9/2)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Really useful tool. @Wiktor Stribiżew